# Differing Blob sizes before and after reading with FileReader

Tags: javascript, blob, filereader

I am trying to read a Blob withe Javascript FileReader API using the following code:

```
reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
  console.log(new Blob([reader.result]));
}
// outBlob defined elsewhere
console.log(outBlob);
reader.readAsBinaryString(outBlob);
```

Running this in Chrome gives:

```
          Blob {type: "undefined", size: 70012, slice: function}
          Blob {type: "", size: 105244, slice: function}
```

My question is, why are the sizes different here?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with some basic _Blob_ `outBlob = new Blob(['foo']);`, so I'm assuming you have some data in your _Blob_ which isn't properly being represented in your _String_... yeah trying with `outBlob = new Blob(['\uF362\uDF4F']);` gives sizes `6` and `12`; it's to do with high valued unicode being respresented in your _String_ differently.

Comment: Thanks. Using readAsArrayBuffer instead solves the issue.